# Dolphin not showing icons in Xfce

Tags: icons, xfce, xrdp, dolphin

I am accessing my Ubuntu server via Win 10 Remote Desktop (XRDP).
The desktop environment is xfce.

When I open dolphin, it does not show the normal icons, as in the left figure.
Compare with the right figure for normal appearance.

**How can I solve this?**

1. [image]                    2. [image]